# How to add a button outside a flutter card in the same page

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I  want to add a button outside a the flutter card on the same page. Unfortunately the code is too long and somewhat private so I would not be able to paste it here. But I would appreciate if help can be rendered. Cheers.

Comment: consider post your code, please.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using a Column? This is basic structure what it should look like, also it's hard to assume when you haven't provided any code or a mock design

```
Column(
children:[
 Card(), 
 RasiedButton()
]
)
```

This will display a card and button outside of the card but just below it.